# Converting a DataTable to an CREATE TABLE + INSERT script for SQL in C#

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, datatable

I need to generate a TSQL script from a DataTable along with the DATA in it.
It's not a single insert. Beside that, I need the create the table too (same datatable structure)

so: I have a DataTable filled with data. I want the TSQL script that creates the structure of this DataTable along with the data in it in SQL SERVER (CREATE TABLE + INSERT)

Thank you in advance
And Special thanks to John Saunders for helping me to correct the question.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? DataTable is fairly primitive technology and has no built-in way of doing what you're asking for.

Comment: I'm using Framework 3.5 vs 2010

Comment: then you should be looking at Entity Framework, which has the ability to create the database model, create the table, and then update it. DataTable is quite outdated.

Comment: in my case a datatable is provided, do I need to create a dataset to get the structure? To read each row in datatable I can do this and append it and have a string of inserts.
For Each iRow as Datarow in dtTable



string strSQL = "INSERT INTO
TestTable(Col1,Col2) VALUES (" + iRow.item("Col1") + "," + iRow.item("Col1") + ")";

Comment: Nonsense, DataTable is not "quite outdated".  Entity Framework is an overkill for a lot of projects.

Answer (score 21):

First, I would use this object to [build your CREATE TABLE command.](http://darrylagostinelli.com/2011/06/27/create-a-sql-table-from-a-datatable-in-c-net/)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace Toolkit
{
    public class SqlTableCreator
    {
        #region Instance Variables
        private SqlConnection _connection;
        public SqlConnection Connection
        {
            get { return _connection; }
            set { _connection = value; }
        }

        private SqlTransaction _transaction;
        public SqlTransaction Transaction
        {
            get { return _transaction; }
            set { _transaction = value; }
        }

        private string _tableName;
        public string DestinationTableName
        {
            get { return _tableName; }
            set { _tableName = value; }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public SqlTableCreator() { }
        public SqlTableCreator(SqlConnection connection) : this(connection, null) { }
        public SqlTableCreator(SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction)
        {
            _connection = connection;
            _transaction = transaction;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Instance Methods
        public object Create(DataTable schema)
        {
            return Create(schema, null);
        }
        public object Create(DataTable schema, int numKeys)
        {
            int[] primaryKeys = new int[numKeys];
            for (int i = 0; i < numKeys; i++)
            {
                primaryKeys[i] = i;
            }
            return Create(schema, primaryKeys);
        }
        public object Create(DataTable schema, int[] primaryKeys)
        {
            string sql = GetCreateSQL(_tableName, schema, primaryKeys);

            SqlCommand cmd;
            if (_transaction != null && _transaction.Connection != null)
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, _connection, _transaction);
            else
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, _connection);

            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        public object CreateFromDataTable(DataTable table)
        {
            string sql = GetCreateFromDataTableSQL(_tableName, table);

            SqlCommand cmd;
            if (_transaction != null && _transaction.Connection != null)
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, _connection, _transaction);
            else
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, _connection);

            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Static Methods

        public static string GetCreateSQL(string tableName, DataTable schema, int[] primaryKeys)
        {
            string sql = "CREATE TABLE [" + tableName + "] (\n";

            // columns
            foreach (DataRow column in schema.Rows)
            {
                if (!(schema.Columns.Contains("IsHidden") && (bool)column["IsHidden"]))
                {
                    sql += "\t[" + column["ColumnName"].ToString() + "] " + SQLGetType(column);

                    if (schema.Columns.Contains("AllowDBNull") && (bool)column["AllowDBNull"] == false)
                        sql += " NOT NULL";

                    sql += ",\n";
                }
            }
            sql = sql.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',', '\n' }) + "\n";

            // primary keys
            string pk = ", CONSTRAINT PK_" + tableName + " PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (";
            bool hasKeys = (primaryKeys != null && primaryKeys.Length > 0);
            if (hasKeys)
            {
                // user defined keys
                foreach (int key in primaryKeys)
                {
                    pk += schema.Rows[key]["ColumnName"].ToString() + ", ";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // check schema for keys
                string keys = string.Join(", ", GetPrimaryKeys(schema));
                pk += keys;
                hasKeys = keys.Length > 0;
            }
            pk = pk.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',', ' ', '\n' }) + ")\n";
            if (hasKeys) sql += pk;

            sql += ")";

            return sql;
        }

        public static string GetCreateFromDataTableSQL(string tableName, DataTable table)
        {
            string sql = "CREATE TABLE [" + tableName + "] (\n";
            // columns
            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                sql += "[" + column.ColumnName + "] " + SQLGetType(column) + ",\n";
            }
            sql = sql.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',', '\n' }) + "\n";
            // primary keys
            if (table.PrimaryKey.Length > 0)
            {
                sql += "CONSTRAINT [PK_" + tableName + "] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (";
                foreach (DataColumn column in table.PrimaryKey)
                {
                    sql += "[" + column.ColumnName + "],";
                }
                sql = sql.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' }) + "))\n";
            }

            //if not ends with ")"
            if ((table.PrimaryKey.Length == 0) && (!sql.EndsWith(")")))
            {
                sql += ")";
            }

            return sql;
        }

        public static string[] GetPrimaryKeys(DataTable schema)
        {
            List<string> keys = new List<string>();

            foreach (DataRow column in schema.Rows)
            {
                if (schema.Columns.Contains("IsKey") && (bool)column["IsKey"])
                    keys.Add(column["ColumnName"].ToString());
            }

            return keys.ToArray();
        }

        // Return T-SQL data type definition, based on schema definition for a column
        public static string SQLGetType(object type, int columnSize, int numericPrecision, int numericScale)
        {
            switch (type.ToString())
            {
                case "System.String":
                    return "VARCHAR(" + ((columnSize == -1) ? "255" : (columnSize > 8000) ? "MAX" : columnSize.ToString() ) + ")";

                case "System.Decimal":
                    if (numericScale > 0)
                        return "REAL";
                    else if (numericPrecision > 10)
                        return "BIGINT";
                    else
                        return "INT";

                case "System.Double":
                case "System.Single":
                    return "REAL";

                case "System.Int64":
                    return "BIGINT";

                case "System.Int16":
                case "System.Int32":
                    return "INT";

                case "System.DateTime":
                    return "DATETIME";

                case "System.Boolean":
                    return "BIT";

                case "System.Byte":
                    return "TINYINT";

                case "System.Guid":
                    return "UNIQUEIDENTIFIER";

                default:
                    throw new Exception(type.ToString() + " not implemented.");
            }
        }

        // Overload based on row from schema table
        public static string SQLGetType(DataRow schemaRow)
        {
            return SQLGetType(schemaRow["DataType"],
                                int.Parse(schemaRow["ColumnSize"].ToString()),
                                int.Parse(schemaRow["NumericPrecision"].ToString()),
                                int.Parse(schemaRow["NumericScale"].ToString()));
        }
        // Overload based on DataColumn from DataTable type
        public static string SQLGetType(DataColumn column)
        {
            return SQLGetType(column.DataType, column.MaxLength, 10, 2);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Then I would use SQL BulkCopy rather than separate INSERT statements.

```
public static void BulkInsertDataTable(string connectionString, string tableName, DataTable table)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                    new SqlBulkCopy
                    (
                    connection,
                    SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock |
                    SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers |
                    SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction,
                    null
                    );

                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                connection.Open();

                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your VARCHAR is missing the end bracket. Try this VARCHAR(" + ((table.Columns[i].MaxLength == -1) ? "255), " : (table.Columns[i].MaxLength > 8000) ? "MAX), " : table.Columns[i].MaxLength.ToString() + "), "));

Answer (score 5):

```
public void createsqltable(DataTable dt,string tablename)
        {
            string strconnection = "";
            string table = "";
            table += "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[" + tablename + "]') AND type in (N'U'))";
            table += "BEGIN ";
            table += "create table " + tablename + "";
            table += "(";
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i != dt.Columns.Count-1)
                    table += dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + " " + "varchar(max)" + ",";
                else
                    table += dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + " " + "varchar(max)";
            }
            table += ") ";
            table += "END";
            InsertQuery(table,strconnection);
            CopyData(strconnection, dt, tablename);
        }
        public void InsertQuery(string qry,string connection)
        {


            SqlConnection _connection = new SqlConnection(connection);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = qry;
            cmd.Connection = _connection;
            _connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            _connection.Close();
        }
        public static void CopyData(string connStr, DataTable dt, string tablename)
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
            new SqlBulkCopy(connStr, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tablename;
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I added curly braces over `dt.Columns[i].ColumnName` to prevent column names throwing error when they contains spaces

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at: [Generate SQL INSERT commands programmatically](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/GenerateSQL.aspx)

Essentially, the code is looping through the DataTable.Columns collection to generate the column list of the INSERT statement. Then it loops through the values of the DataTable to create the parameters with values.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the tool created by me if you want to create the `insert` script from the table.
This creates `Insert` script on multiple table based on condition given:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (Select 1 from Table1 WHERE Col1='Col1' AND Col2='Col2')
INSERT INTO Table1 (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4) VALUES (1,'abc',null,'2012-01-01')
```

Here is the link: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/330864/Generate-Insert-script-to-extract-data

Comment: I read that article twice, but its not clear what is it doing.