# DataTable to SQL Server tables with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datatable

I have a dataset with several tables and relations in the dataset. I would like to be able to use entity framework to then translate my dataset tables into an SQL server set of tables. I see articles for filling the tables - but literally how would I go about some pseudo code like this.

```
for each dataTable in ds.Tables
{
    Create a table in SQL Server with these columns
}
```

After creation then I want to add in the relations .. and then fill with data.

I get these tables in the dataset by reading in an xml file, I have classes that were created by xsd.exe

Comment: WOW, it could be a project. not just a question. Latest EF supports code-first, it means you have to hard code schema first. but you can also use Scaffold-Context to reverse database, but you have to hard code database first.

Comment: So you want an API to create database objects for SQL Server, did i got you right? EF could be used to insert that data, but if you want to create the db structure from that method, you will need SMO

Comment: But it's still possible to create table, but you don't have to use EF, since ADO.NET is enough to do the work.

Comment: @moro91 Yes I am importing XML files and I would like to do a simple thing kind of like EF.Table.Create,  but I guess the old hard way is the only way.

Comment: @Dongdong my schema is in the dataset and datatables that are imported from xml / via the class translation files I generated using xsd.exe. I have an xsd file as well for validation of xml.

Comment: Yeah, the only way I know to do that is to use the SQL Management Objects library, Microsoft provides it to manipulate a SQL database by just using an API in C#. I don't think EF goal is to support this kind of operations

Comment: @moro91 - I found a method without SMO and added some code to perform relations. My portions are the not so pretty - but it seems to work fine - I have not verified it on composite keys but I think they should work as well. I posted as a non-Answer answer (after all it does not use Entity Framework) but for the sake of others who might want to do something similar can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I can not say I am answering the question exactly as posed - because there seems to be no entity framework solution to the problem. However, my main point in posting this answer is in case someone else is looking for code to translate a dataset, its tables and relations and then create those in SQLServer. The Code below uses standard .NET libraries of SQLClient. No SMO is used.

The Bulk of this code is not mine but rather came from User: 010110110101, [Converting a DataTable to an CREATE TABLE + INSERT script for SQL in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227306/converting-a-datatable-to-an-create-table-insert-script-for-sql-in-c-sharp/6499682#6499682)

My main contribution to the code was to fix some minor bugs in the code, and also add the Alter Table sql , along with the methods for generating the Relations.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace Helpers.Sql
{

    public class TableCreator
    {
        #region Instance Variables
        private SqlConnection _connection;
        public SqlConnection Connection
        {
            get { return _connection; }
            set { _connection = value; }
        }

        private SqlTransaction _transaction;
        public SqlTransaction Transaction
        {
            get { return _transaction; }
            set { _transaction = value; }
        }

        private string _tableName;
        public string DestinationTableName
        {
            get { return _tableName; }
            set { _tableName = value; }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public TableCreator() { }
        public TableCreator(SqlConnection connection) : this(connection, null) { }
        public TableCreator(SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction)
        {
            _connection = connection;
            _transaction = transaction;
        }

        public TableCreator(string connectionString)
        {

            this.Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        }


        #endregion

        #region Instance Methods
        public object Create(DataTable schema)
        {
            return Create(schema, null);
        }
        public object Create(DataTable schema, int numKeys)
        {
            int[] primaryKeys = new int[numKeys];
            for (int i = 0; i < numKeys; i++)
            {
                primaryKeys[i] = i;
            }
            return Create(schema, primaryKeys);
        }
        public object Create(DataTable schema, int[] primaryKeys)
        {
            string sql = GetCreateSQL(_tableName, schema, primaryKeys);

            SqlCommand cmd;
            if (_transaction != null && _transaction.Connection != null)
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, _connection, _transaction);
            else
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, _connection);

            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        public object CreateFromDataTable(DataTable table)
        {
            DestinationTableName = table.TableName;

            string sql = GetCreateFromDataTableSQL(_tableName, table);

            SqlCommand cmd;
            if (_transaction != null && _transaction.Connection != null)
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, _connection, _transaction);
            else
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, _connection);

            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Data Relation
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="_relation"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public object CreateRelationFromDataSet(DataRelation _relation)
        {

            string sql = GetCreateFromDatSetRelations(_relation);

            SqlCommand cmd;
            if (_transaction != null && _transaction.Connection != null)
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, _connection, _transaction);
            else
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, _connection);

            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }


        #endregion

        #region Static Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="tableName"></param>
        /// <param name="schema"></param>
        /// <param name="primaryKeys"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string GetCreateSQL(string tableName, DataTable schema, int[] primaryKeys)
        {
            string sql = "CREATE TABLE [" + tableName + "] (\n";

            // columns
            foreach (DataRow column in schema.Rows)
            {
                if (!(schema.Columns.Contains("IsHidden") && (bool)column["IsHidden"]))
                {
                    sql += "\t[" + column["ColumnName"].ToString() + "] " + SQLGetType(column);

                    if (schema.Columns.Contains("AllowDBNull") && (bool)column["AllowDBNull"] == false)
                        sql += " NOT NULL";

                    sql += ",\n";
                }
            }
            sql = sql.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',', '\n' }) + "\n";

            // primary keys
            string pk = ", CONSTRAINT PK_" + tableName + " PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (";
            bool hasKeys = (primaryKeys != null && primaryKeys.Length > 0);
            if (hasKeys)
            {
                // user defined keys
                foreach (int key in primaryKeys)
                {
                    pk += schema.Rows[key]["ColumnName"].ToString() + ", ";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // check schema for keys
                string keys = string.Join(", ", GetPrimaryKeys(schema));
                pk += keys;
                hasKeys = keys.Length > 0;
            }
            pk = pk.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',', ' ', '\n' }) + ")\n";
            if (hasKeys) sql += pk;

            sql += ")";

            return sql;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="tableName"></param>
        /// <param name="table"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string GetCreateFromDataTableSQL(string tableName, DataTable table)
        {
            string sql = "CREATE TABLE [" + tableName + "] (\n";
            // columns
            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                sql += "[" + column.ColumnName + "] " + SQLGetType(column) + ",\n";
            }
            sql = sql.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',', '\n' }) + "\n";
            // primary keys
            if (table.PrimaryKey.Length > 0)
            {
                sql += "CONSTRAINT [PK_" + tableName + "] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (";
                foreach (DataColumn column in table.PrimaryKey)
                {
                    sql += "[" + column.ColumnName + "],";
                }
                sql = sql.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' }) + "))\n";
            }

            //if not ends with ")"
            if ((table.PrimaryKey.Length == 0) && (!sql.EndsWith(")")))
            {
                sql += ")";
            }

            return sql;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="relation"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string GetCreateFromDatSetRelations(DataRelation relation)
        {

            // string sql = "";

            string childTableName = relation.ChildTable.TableName;
            string parentTableName = relation.ParentTable.TableName;

            string sql = "ALTER TABLE [" + childTableName + "] ADD CONSTRAINT \n";

            //sql += "ADD CONSTRAINT \n";

            // Add the relation - if the name is in the dataset use it.
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(relation.RelationName))
            {
                sql += "FK_" + childTableName + "_" + parentTableName;
            }
            else
            {
                sql += relation.RelationName;
            }

            sql += " FOREIGN KEY \n(\n";

            // Set up the keys for the Columns that have foreign 

            for (int i = 0; i < relation.ChildKeyConstraint.Columns.Length; i++)
            {

                sql += relation.ChildKeyConstraint.Columns[i].ColumnName;

                if ((relation.ChildKeyConstraint.Columns.Length > 1 ) & i < (relation.ChildKeyConstraint.Columns.Length - 1))
                {
                    sql += ",";
                }

                sql += "\n";

            }


            // Set up the reference columns.

            sql += "\n) REFERENCES " + parentTableName + "\n(\n";

            //   int cols = relation.ParentKeyConstraint.Columns.Length;

            for (int i = 0; i < relation.ParentKeyConstraint.Columns.Length; i++)
            {

                sql += relation.ParentKeyConstraint.Columns[i].ColumnName;

                if ((relation.ParentKeyConstraint.Columns.Length > 1) & i < (relation.ParentKeyConstraint.Columns.Length - 1))
                {
                    sql += ",";
                }

                sql += "\n";

            }

            sql += ") \n ON UPDATE NO ACTION  \n ON DELETE NO ACTION";


            return sql;
        }




        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="schema"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string[] GetPrimaryKeys(DataTable schema)
        {
            List<string> keys = new List<string>();

            foreach (DataRow column in schema.Rows)
            {
                if (schema.Columns.Contains("IsKey") && (bool)column["IsKey"])
                    keys.Add(column["ColumnName"].ToString());
            }

            return keys.ToArray();
        }

        // Return T-SQL data type definition, based on schema definition for a column
        public static string SQLGetType(object type, int columnSize, int numericPrecision, int numericScale)
        {
            switch (type.ToString())
            {
                case "System.String":
                    return "VARCHAR(" + ((columnSize == -1) ? "255" : (columnSize > 8000) ? "MAX" : columnSize.ToString()) + ")";

                case "System.Decimal":
                    if (numericScale > 0)
                        return "REAL";
                    else if (numericPrecision > 10)
                        return "BIGINT";
                    else
                        return "INT";

                case "System.Double":
                case "System.Single":
                    return "REAL";

                case "System.Int64":
                    return "BIGINT";

                case "System.Int16":
                case "System.Int32":
                    return "INT";

                case "System.DateTime":
                    return "DATETIME";

                case "System.Boolean":
                    return "BIT";

                case "System.Byte":
                    return "TINYINT";

                case "System.Guid":
                    return "UNIQUEIDENTIFIER";

                default:
                    throw new Exception(type.ToString() + " not implemented.");
            }
        }

        // Overload based on row from schema table
        public static string SQLGetType(DataRow schemaRow)
        {
            return SQLGetType(schemaRow["DataType"],
                                int.Parse(schemaRow["ColumnSize"].ToString()),
                                int.Parse(schemaRow["NumericPrecision"].ToString()),
                                int.Parse(schemaRow["NumericScale"].ToString()));
        }
        // Overload based on DataColumn from DataTable type
        public static string SQLGetType(DataColumn column)
        {
            return SQLGetType(column.DataType, column.MaxLength, 10, 2);
        }
        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connectionString"></param>
        /// <param name="tableName"></param>
        /// <param name="table"></param>
        public static void BulkInsertDataTable(string connectionString, string tableName, DataTable table)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                    new SqlBulkCopy
                    (
                    connection,
                    SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock |
                    SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers |
                    SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction,
                    null
                    );

                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                connection.Open();

                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public class CreateServerModel
    {

        public void CreateServerTables(DataSet ds, SqlConnection conn)
        {

            TableCreator STC = new TableCreator(conn);

            STC.Connection.Open();
            foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
            {

                STC.CreateFromDataTable(dt);

            }
            STC.Connection.Close();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ds"></param>
        /// <param name="conn"></param>
        public void CreateTableRelations(DataSet ds, SqlConnection conn)
        {

            TableCreator STC = new TableCreator(conn);

            STC.Connection.Open();

            foreach (DataRelation relation in ds.Relations)
            {
                //STC.Get
                //string chTblName = item.ChildTable.TableName;
                //string prntTblName = item.ParentTable.TableName;


                //List<DataColumn> lchColumns = relation.ChildKeyConstraint.Columns.ToList();
                //List<DataColumn> parColumns = relation.ParentKeyConstraint.Columns.ToList();
                //string prntTblName = relation.ParentTable.TableName;
                try
                {
                    STC.CreateRelationFromDataSet(relation);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string msg = ex.Message.ToString();
                    // throw;
                    msg += "";
                }


            }

            STC.Connection.Close();
        }

    }
}
```