# SSIS write dynamic results set variable to MSSQL table

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, ssis, etl

I'm creating an SSIS application that writes dynamic SQL results (read: variable number and names of columns) to a ComObject variable named `User::ResultSet`.

I now want to create an SSIS task that drops the table `testTable` if it exists, then reads the ComObject variable and inserts it into the `testTable` table in MSSQL Server. So in essence, I want to do this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.testTable;

SELECT *
INTO dbo.testTable
FROM [User::ResultSet]
```

Is this possible in SSIS 2015, without knowing the types, names, and number of columns in the ComObject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, plain SSIS without script objects cannot do it. SSIS is metadata centric, it has to know column names and types before package run. SSIS runtime environment does not allow altering metadata definition on the fly.

However, you can do what you want in a Script Task. Here is the approach:

1. Object type Variable used by a ComObject with Full Result Set is either `ADO Recordset` (if you used OLEDB Connection Manager), or `ADO DataSet` (if you used ADO.NET CM). In the former case, convert `ADO Recordset` to `ADO DataTable` with similar code.

   ```
   using System.Data.OleDb;  

   public void Main()
   {
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
       oleda.Fill(dt, this.Variables.ObjectVariable);
   ```
2. Then, having DataTable object filled with values and metadata, you can create SQL `Create Table` statement and then - perform Bulk insert of data from DataTable. Here is an [excellent code example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6499682/1010622).

Your Script Task will create SQL Table based on metadata from DataTable, and then copy its content to the newly created table.

Comment: I suspected that it was possible with Script Tasks. Thank you for this excellent answer, I'll give it a test run today